# bring touched views to the front layer in objective-c/cocoa touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

So what i want to do is when any given UIView is touched, and moved around the window, to bring that to the front and be on top of all other layers. is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move a subview to the top of all subviews by using [bringSubviewToFront:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:)